# IPConfiguration apple80211Open() crashes on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, network-programming

I am trying to read RSSI of iPhone WIFI connection to AP.

Using Xcode 6.1.1 with iPhone6+ ios 8.1.3

Code below crashes at `apple80211Open()` and gets E`XC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address= 0)` on iOS 8.   (code works on iOS 7.1)

This is for app that is NOT for Apple Store -- for adhoc distribution only.

=================================================================

```
void *libHandle;
   void *airportHandle;

   int (*apple80211Open)(void *);
   int (*apple80211Bind)(void *, NSString *);
   int (*apple80211Close)(void *);
   int (*apple80211GetInfoCopy)(void *, CFDictionaryRef *);

   NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
   NSDictionary * tempDictionary;
   libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration", RTLD_LAZY);

   char *dlerror_error;

   if (libHandle == NULL && (dlerror_error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
      NSLog(@"%s", dlerror_error);
   }

   apple80211Open = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Open");
   apple80211Bind = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211BindToInterface");
   apple80211Close = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Close");
   apple80211GetInfoCopy = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211GetInfoCopy");

   apple80211Open(&airportHandle);
   apple80211Bind(airportHandle, @"en0");

   CFDictionaryRef info = NULL;

   apple80211GetInfoCopy(airportHandle, &info);

   tempDictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)info;

   apple80211Close(airportHandle);

   [infoDict setObject:(tempDictionary[@"RSSI"])[@"RSSI_CTL_AGR"] ? (tempDictionary[@"RSSI"])[@"RSSI_CTL_AGR"] : @"0" forKey:@"RSSI"];

   [infoDict setObject:tempDictionary[@"BSSID"] ? tempDictionary[@"BSSID"] : @"null" forKey:@"BSSID"];

   [infoDict setObject:tempDictionary[@"SSID_STR"] ? tempDictionary[@"SSID_STR"] : @"null" forKey:@"SSID"];

   [infoDict setObject:tempDictionary[@"RATE"] ? tempDictionary[@"RATE"] : @"0" forKey:@"SPEED"];
```

Comment: I have the same problem... Some idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Apple removed the 80211 framework from within IPConfiguration. The symbols can't be found, dlsym returns NULL, and - a crash (you should always check return values, you know).

To begin with, this was a private framework. In new versions of iOS (8+), it's deprecated in favor of MobileWifi, and the use of entitlements (and XPC) so as to have /usr/libexec/wifid to all the work.

There's more detail on this in this article: http://newosxbook.com/articles/11208ellpA.html

Comment: If Apple did remove it then it's back again, Apple80211 methods are inside IPConfiguration in iOS 13.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The Apple80211 API was removed from IPConfiguration at some point e.g. iOS 11 & 12, but came back in iOS 13 and as of today the methods are all still there and working in iOS 13.4.1. What I expect is the reason you were unable to get it working is likely since iOS 8 you need the `com.apple.wlan.authentication` entitlement as mentioned [here](http://newosxbook.com/articles/11208ellpA-II.html).

There is currently a [sneaky way](https://siguza.github.io/psychicpaper/) to use this entitlement in apps (for your own use), but it will stop working in iOS 13.5.